# How to make use of DTO, domain model, value object,

Tags: c#, architecture, poco, dto, domain-object

I am designing the different layers of a scheduler in c#. This is going to be a service running in the background without a GUI.

This is my baseline for the architecture (of course only being a small snippet of the structure.

![1] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v34D6.png)

I am uncertain about "best-practice" in terms of architecture. I have been reading about, POCOs, Value Objects, DTOs, Domain Model and from what I can understand, the presented below is a wrong approach to DTOs.

In my class "ScheduleDTP", I have several methods doing some relatively complex manipulations with date coming from the database. `CalculatePriority` is a simplified example of one of the methods

Database properties:

```
ID, Name, Frequency, LastRun
```

Manipulated properties:

```
Priority
```

The purpose of the jobmanager is to evaluate all schedules and on-demands.

To my understanding the DTO should only contain the data, and transfer that between the different layers. I also believe that this should not be the JobManagers responsibility either.

```
public class ScheduleDTO
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRun { get; set; }

    //Calculation based on the values above
    public double Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return CalculatePriority();
        }
    }

    public double CalculatePriority()
    {
        return (DateTime.Now - LastRun.AddSeconds(Frequency)).TotalSeconds / 100;
    }
}
```

Should I create some different type of object, POCO, Domail Model, ..., that manipulates the data in the DTOs?

I really appreciate any help about how to construct the different layers or something that that could lead me in the right direction

Comment: Is a Scheduled Job actually different from an On Demand Job? Or, is it the way that a job is started that is different? Have you considered that maybe you do not need a Job Manager to start a job, but you instead need a Scheduler to trigger a job? There are too many details missing from your question for us to recommend a robust OO design. But what I can say is, your top layer looks suspiciously thin.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally handled by a Service layer (aka business logic layer, BLL, etc).  The service layer's job is to hold the core business logic.  There exists a long-standing argument about whether this layer should be used, or if it should be integrated into the domain objects.  [See this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863021/layered-design-architecture/49863806) and do some googling about anemic domain models and transaction scripts.

In general, when I see anything called "Manager", I immediately flag it for close inspection.  It is likely violating rules around [Single Responsibility Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  It ends up creating "God Objects" which are usually a very dangerous anti-pattern.